# How to loop values of different dictionaries and append them in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

i need to loop the values of different dictionaries and create a data frame out of them.

the data is from an api which outputs a json, that looks like the following

**Source Dictionairy**

```
result = {
    "meta": {
        "request": {
            "segment_name": "Searches1",
            "metrics": ["Visits"]
        },
        "status": "Success"
    },
    "segments": [
        {"date": "2021-11-01", "visits": 100, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-02", "visits": 200, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-03", "visits": 300, "confidence": "Low"},
        {"date": "2021-11-04", "visits": 400, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-05", "visits": 500, "confidence": "Low"},
    ]
},
{
    "meta": {
        "request": {
            "segment_name": "Searches2",
            "metrics": ["Visits"]
        },
        "status": "Success"
    },
    "segments": [
        {"date": "2021-11-01", "visits": 110, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-02", "visits": 220, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-03", "visits": 330, "confidence": "Low"},
        {"date": "2021-11-04", "visits": 440, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-05", "visits": 540, "confidence": "Low"},
    ]
}
```

I tried with the following approach where i just loop the "segments"-dictionairy but this obviously doesn't work.

**My Approach**

```
def getSearches():

    Searches = []
    segment_name = result['meta']['request']['segment_name']

    if "segments" in result:
        for fs in result['segments']:
            Searches.append(
                {"date": fs['date'], "segment_name": segment_name, "visits": fs['visits'], "confidence": fs['confidence']})

    fs_df = pd.DataFrame(Searches)
    print(fs_df)


getSearches()
```

I get the following error message

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ismail/Desktop/sw_dict_test", line 51, in <module>
    getFlightSearches()
  File "/Users/ismail/Desktop/sw_dict_test", line 40, in getFlightSearches
    segment_name = result['meta']['request']['segment_name']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

to be exact i need to access the "segment_name" from the "request" dictionairy as well as all the variables in the "segments" dictionairy and append them in a pandas table.

**Desired Output**

```
         date segment_name  visits confidence
0  2021-11-01    Searches1     100       High
1  2021-11-02    Searches1     200       High
2  2021-11-03    Searches1     300        Low
3  2021-11-04    Searches1     400       High
4  2021-11-05    Searches1     500        Low
5  2021-11-01    Searches2     110       High
6  2021-11-02    Searches2     220       High
7  2021-11-03    Searches2     330        Low
8  2021-11-04    Searches2     440       High
9  2021-11-05    Searches2     550        Low
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `json_normalize` to flatten the JSON data. Since the list of records, i.e. the dicts that you need to convert to rows are stored in "segments", set `record_path='segments'`. You only use "segment_name" as metadata for each record, so you set the path to it as a list: `meta=[['meta', 'request', 'segment_name']]`.

Then use `rename` to change a column name and `reindex` to get the columns in correct order.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(result, 'segments', [['meta', 'request', 'segment_name']]).rename({'meta.request.segment_name':'segment_name'}, axis=1).reindex(['date', 'segment_name', 'visits', 'confidence'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         date segment_name  visits confidence
0  2021-11-01    Searches1     100       High
1  2021-11-02    Searches1     200       High
2  2021-11-03    Searches1     300        Low
3  2021-11-04    Searches1     400       High
4  2021-11-05    Searches1     500        Low
5  2021-11-01    Searches2     110       High
6  2021-11-02    Searches2     220       High
7  2021-11-03    Searches2     330        Low
8  2021-11-04    Searches2     440       High
9  2021-11-05    Searches2     540        Low
```

Comment: i really like this approach, but why are the entries repeating themselves for each day? i guess this is not the expected outcome, right?

Comment: @please_be_nice I edited to fix the issue. Sorry about that. I also added a bit more explanation

Comment: thank you for your reply and your additional information. this works really nice.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a tuple, hence the error. Make it a list instead and loop over each element.

```
result = [{
    "meta": {
        "request": {
            "segment_name": "Searches1",
            "metrics": ["Visits"]
        },
        "status": "Success"
    },
    "segments": [
        {"date": "2021-11-01", "visits": 100, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-02", "visits": 200, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-03", "visits": 300, "confidence": "Low"},
        {"date": "2021-11-04", "visits": 400, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-05", "visits": 500, "confidence": "Low"},
    ]
},
{
    "meta": {
        "request": {
            "segment_name": "Searches2",
            "metrics": ["Visits"]
        },
        "status": "Success"
    },
    "segments": [
        {"date": "2021-11-01", "visits": 110, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-02", "visits": 220, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-03", "visits": 330, "confidence": "Low"},
        {"date": "2021-11-04", "visits": 440, "confidence": "High"},
        {"date": "2021-11-05", "visits": 540, "confidence": "Low"},
    ]
}]


def getSearches(result):

    Searches = []
    segment_name = result['meta']['request']['segment_name']

    if "segments" in result:
        for fs in result['segments']:
            Searches.append(
                {"date": fs['date'], "segment_name": segment_name, "visits": fs['visits'], "confidence": fs['confidence']})

    return Searches

searches = []
for r in result:
    searches += getSearches(r)
    
pd.DataFrame(searches)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. What if the result variable gets defined within the function? In this case it wouldn't work. How would i approach this?

Comment: It would still work, just put everything in `getSearches` and make it parameterless. You could also wrap the `result` generating code in a new function along with the all the hanging code. That way the logic for parsing results is separated a bit.